# Doctrine2 with dynamic relationships base on a value

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

What I'm trying to do is basically Entity A which have field **type** to relate with Entity B or C base on the value of field **type**

for example: a **Product** if is type drinks to be related with **DrinkOptions** entity, but if it's with type food to be related with **FoodOptions** entity

Is there any elegant solution which can work fine in such case?
This is what I thought it will work, but it doesn't..

- Changing dynamically the entity A relation will not help, because it's not yet loaded and I can't see the value of field **type**
- combine the different option entities into one, but it will be very ugly picture with 200+ properties..
- define all option types in the config and then dynamically create the mapping with the loadClassMetadata, but is not so pretty also it requires a "dummy" property, getters and setters for all option types in the **Entity A**

Comment: Can you add some context: Why do you need to do it?

Comment: the context is actually similar as the example.. Entity Product can be with many types like wine, cheese, spirits, t-shirts, etc.. every type have it's own Entity like WineOptions, CheeseOptions, etc.. which will hold the type specific properties. The thing is that is not very pretty to relate the Product to all possible option types, so I'm trying to figure out how to relate Product Wine with WineOptions, Product Cheese with CheeseOptions... you've got the idea I guess

Comment: What about implementing a metamodel, is it overkill? or something simpler like ProductOption?

Comment: every type contain it's own simple fields (string, text,  integer...) and also it's own mappings with other entities and translations. With the ProductOption will not work in that case, but what do you have in mind with the meta model thing ?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solutions could be to use a single table inheritance. Might not be the nicest solution but it could fit your specific need.

```
<?php
namespace MyProject\Model;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="discriminator", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"drink" = "DrinkOption", "food" = "FoodOption"})
 */
class Option
{
    // ...
}

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class FoodOption extends Option
{
    // ...
}

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class DrinkOption extends Option
{
    // ...
}
```

You then could even switch the type by altering the "discriminator" column.

Comment: I don't think this will solve the main problem, because the Product will sill have to be mapped to FoodOption or to DrinkOption..

Comment: why not use a manyToMany in between of option and product? that sort of has to be done in your business logic, unless you haven't multiple tables for each kind of your product, a relational database can not differ them

Answer (score 0):

I think the simpliest way would be to have multiple product entities with an inheritence

Like Product (parent) -> foodProduct (child) or DrinkProduct().

This way you could have Product link to common others entities (like price or brand) and specific link for food, drinks, smokes etc...

```
Product
  id:
  type: food/drink/smoke etc..
  foodproduct: one to Many nullable: FoodProduct (it's actually one to zero/one but i find it more performant)
  drinkproduct: one to Many nullable: DrinkProduct 
  smokeproduct:one to Many nullable: SmokeProduct 


FoodProduct:
  id:
  product_id (many to one to Product)
  options one to many to foodOptions
```

If it still don't fit you will have to find some design pattern

Comment: this was also a possibility, but the management of the Products in general will be very difficult right? If you want to see all products you will query few tables in the DB

Comment: No you could query the product table